# Wordpress login form script

Tags: login

I am looking for something very simple but I'm not quite sure how to achieve this. I have been researching for the past 2-3 hours and gathered a lot of useful information. However, my knowledge in both PHP and WordPress isn't enough to do this from scratch.

What I need is the following:

- When the user is **not** logged in, this HTML code should be displayed:

  ```
  <a href="#">Login</a>
  ```
- When the user **is** logged in, the previous HTML code should be replaced with:

  ```
  <span>Welcome, *username*</span>
  <a href="actual-link-for-logging-out-the-user">Logout</a>
  ```

Could anyone please help me out. I'd really appreciate the help :)

Thanks

Comment: Those messages should be displayed where?

Comment: I know nut about codex however I would want to input the below codex in my website. Appreciate you could advise where should I input the codex? global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo(); if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { echo "<span>Welcome $current_user->user_login</span>". "<a href='".wp_logout_url()."'>Logout</a>";
} else { echo '<a href="#">Login</a>';
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to use the [`is_user_logged_in()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) conditional tag to handle this.

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
  echo "<span>Welcome $current_user->user_login</span>".
       "<a href='".wp_logout_url()."'>Logout</a>";
} else {
  echo '<a href="#">Login</a>';
}
```

Other functions referenced: [wp_logout_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout_url) & [get_currentuserinfo()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo)

FYI, all of this could easily be found on Google or in the [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/).

Comment: +1 for the Answer as a whole, -0.5 for the FYI. Especially for beginners in a tech (like PHP or WordPress), it's not so easy to craft the correct search terms to find an answer to your problem.

Comment: @AKTed: Give a man a fish, and all of that...

Comment: Hey Dan, thanks a lot! You're awesome! That works perfectly and was exactly what I was looking for.